# AdonisJS Request Origin

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I would like to retrieve the request's origin using adonisJS framework. Is there any way similar to express.js:

```
 req.get('origin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "host" and "origin" header using this: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/request#_headers

Comment: I have already checked the headers. There is a host property but not an origin.

Comment: This is possible because by default browsers add this header to sort out CORS. If you dont have it, it could mean that request was not sent from the browser and you shoud adapt/inform user of api to add headers you need.

Comment: Thank you. Problem was I was expecting the origin header when sending requests from same machine the api is running. I tried with a different machine in the network and it worked.